# Crystal Report - A number or currency amount is required here

Tags: arrays, string, split, crystal-reports

A column in DB has comma separated values like BO,UN,UP. (BO - Bold, UN - underline, UP - upperline). The crystal report should be formatted based on the style assigned for a particular record in DB.

Doing this in C# or DB is easy but if any style property is added in future, will require lot of changes. So I am trying to set the formula for bold in crystal report by splitting the column value as shown below.

```
Table Name: AccountsReport
Column Name: Style; Type: String

NumberVar i;
If ',' In {AccountsReport.Style}
Then (
    StringVar Array styles := Split ({AccountsReport.Style}, ",");
    For i := 1 To UBound(styles) Do (
        If styles[i] = "BO" Then (
            crBold; 
            Exit For;
        )
    );
)
```

But getting "A number or currency amount is required here" error and not able to find which line throws that error. Googled the error but no luck.

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe error is not in this formula? I copied it - No errors found. You could change logic - return some color always (use variable); maybe CR doesn't like cases when no value is returned.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. But as it expects a color, it is not possible to return a variable. Also simple If statement without else block as below works.

If {AccountsReport.Style} = "BO" Then
    crBold;

Comment: Hmm, no idea then. Use something like `if instr(',' + {field} + ',', ',BO,') then crBold` (or whatever syntax instr() requires).

Comment: Thanks Arvo. It works. But I 'd like to know what is wrong in the above code, I mean the splitting method.

Comment: Crystal errors are not always helpful. Believe me your problem could be completly unrelated to the error... So as long as you got it working..move on..